# Projector equal to identity matrix

Tags: matrices, projection

I have a simple question. If I take a projector f with matrix $M$, then I have :

$$M^{2}=M$$, so by multiplying by $M^{-1}$ on the right, I get :

$MMM^{-1}= I_{d}$, so $M=I_{d}$, but we can find matrices $M$ which are not identity and represent a projector.

Where is my error ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies in assuming that $M$ is invertible. Actually, you proved that the only invertible projection is the identity.

Comment: -@José Carlos Santos. thanks, so when we get in generally a projector matrix (different from Identity), it is not invertible, is it ?

Comment: Think about what a projection does geometrically. It maps vectors to a subspace, like the shadow of a figure on a wall. You cannot reproduce the figure from the shadow.

Comment: Yes. If we are projecting over a subspace which is not the whole space, then the projection map is not surjective and therefore it is not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

If $M^2=M$, then we have:

$M$ is invertible $ \iff M=Id$.

Hence (if $M^2=M$), the

$M$ is not invertible $ \iff M \ne Id$.

Try also to prove: if $M^2=M$, then the only possible eigenvalues of $M$ are $0$ and $1$.